# Authentication Error while trying to get the DHL Interface to run

Tags: c#, dhl

I've been trying to get the DHL interface up and running for some time now.

Unfortunately, there is already a lack of authentication.

Request:

```
client_id == AppID
client_secret = AppToken

    var client = new RestClient("https://api.dhlecs.com/auth/v4/accesstoken");
    
    client.Timeout = -1;
    
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
    request.AddParameter("client_id", client_id);
    request.AddParameter("client_secret", client_secret);
    
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Response:

> {"type":"https://api.dhlecs.com/docs/errors/401.0000007", "title":"Invalid
> credentials"}

Does anyone have any idea why it doesn't work? Or am I calling something wrong?

Comment: Hi! This is an English website. Please translate your question...

Comment: Sorry, one moment :-)

Comment: `client_id == AppID` should it be `client_id = AppID`??

Comment: It would help if you could also translate your question title into English.